# How to find usages of inherited properties with Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

I need to find all usages of a base class property that is accessed via a particular derived class.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
}

public class AnotherConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
}

public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        ConcreteClass cc = new ConcreteClass();
        cc.Prop = "Value";

        AnotherConcreteClass acc = new AnotherConcreteClass();
        acc.Prop = "Value";
    }
}
```

For instance, I just want to get the usage of `Prop` with `ConcreteClass`.

Can this be done with Resharper?

Comment: Totally agree that this is a duplicate